# How to get data from dataserver in laravel 5.4 and set them as cookie?

Tags: php, sql, cookies, laravel-5.4

I want to create defaults values for my web as cookies in laravel 5.4. 
The data will taken from db server as SQL.

For example: I want to set the daufalt language as hebrew, and in my data I have parameter that tell me if the site is RTL or LTR.

How can I create function like this and call it?

Comment: You can create a localization middleware and set it after the user session has been initialized. There you can set language and other settings for the application to work with. No need into storing this in the cookie as the data is fetched from the db and if it does not exist yet, you can default it to hebrew, rtl or whatever.

Comment: But I need before the user is logged to set the language translate

Comment: That is your default value then? You can set default language (locale) in config/app.php to hebrew. You can also add a setting in your config for text_direction and default to `rtl`. That will be your default behaviour, when user after login sets English as their language, you can get that value from the logged in user and set it in your middleware (same for text_direction).